President sacrificed to kill the alien but failed?
At first, I'm not native English speaker and I don't have many friends from outside countries.
Scene: 

*"The president (or someone similar, vice president, maybe...) was about going to sacrificed himself to destroy a alien in a building (or
  somewhere looks alike) by take a rocket into it (he's in the same building as well as that alien). Everything blew up,
  fire and dust everywhere, few moment later, smoke was getting thinner,
  just to revealed that the alien didn't even take a scratch, and seem
  the president died for nothing..."

Note: Alien doesn't mean space monster like things in Alien series. In scene above, I not clearly remember, but seems alien in human appearance.
<-- which movie that scene came from? (I'm aware of the possibility that maybe it's well-known movie in US, but I live in different country, small one in asia, so it's still hard to find it out without knowing the title/actor/name/anything specified to google).
When I was a kid I watched a middle scene (or last, not sure) of a scifi-action movie which I didn't know the name. For years, I don't really bother to find out it and also hard to find 'coz that time it's just a scene in a movie and I 've no clues about it at all. Today I suddenly recall it after watching another movie (which not related to the one that I find at all). I ask here hope people will be able to tell me what is that movie name? Thanks

And I notice a strange permission issue with my account here (seems doesn't occur in another stackexchange sections).
That's I'm unable to answer a unanswered question here. I saw a question that I know answer but when click on it and read it, can't answer and can't comment as well (requies 50p for comment permission).
I try click into question already answered then I can write a answer in text editor field. But in unanswered one, there's no text field to write, nothing, blank uneditable space.

Is it possible the question you are trying to answer is "protected"?  Some questions have protection to stop low level reputation users answering questions, as the question gets a lot of low quality or spam answers.  I've upvoted you to try to get you some reputation!

As far as I try, I think it's not the case. Because that unanswered question is just new, posted after my question a few minutes, and there's no chance it get enough spam answers (if any) from anyone to a point it being "protected" in that short of time range. But I get it as some kind of default protection (I tried with 6-7 unanswered questions from unanswered list and I'm unable to reply none of them). Maybe globally, in this movie exchange, new/low rep user wasn't allowed to answer unanswered question?

No, that is not the case, we get plenty of 1 rep users posting answers here.  Can I suggest all the boring - restart your browser, clear your cache things?

Also, post a link to what you're trying to answer so we have some context :D

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103003/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_32 Suburban Commando. That's a guess.

Oh, that imdb links to a action/comedy movie?! Surely it's not what I expected when I asked the question, but let me check out more info about it. I checked out some Youtube video and yet haven't found the scene described above. I'll keep checking out more footages from that movie.

It would probably be in the first 10 minutes of the movie or the final battle at the end, but I believe the President was only in the first 10 minutes.

I Can't find out the mentioned scene. If you know exactly footage then it'd be nice... but for now, I think it isn't the movie in question. Anyway, thanks.

Could it have been War of the Worlds?

@Chloe First, thanks for taking a look my question.
I think it's not the movie you link. The overall graphic VFX quality was about 90' or at least close to those years. The 195x movie isn't that, and the characters from that Youtube trailer, they don't fit what is in my mind.

This sounds like the academy award winning and science fiction disaster film:  Independence day.

As for the scene you saw, I don't think you really remembered well. What happened is:
The president launched his aircraft into the center of the alien weapon in a suicide attack, annihilating the ship. Hiller and David, who have discovered the aliens preparing a large ground invasion force, are discovered aboard the mothership. They are unable to make their planned escape and release their missile into the center of the mothership.  
After releasing the weapon they manage to escape before the device detonates, destroying the mothership. Hiller and David return to earth unharmed and the world celebrated. Sadly, this is the scene you never saw or remembered.
And yes it is a well known in the USA, and it grossed $817,400,891 in box office, check the ending scene here on YouTube and verify and if it's the movie you had in mind.

President Whitmore was neither the suicide pilot (that was Casse) nor aboard the craft that entered the mothership. That was Levinson (and Hiller). However, earlier in the movie Whitmore reluctantly gives the order to use nukes against a destroyer. Houston is effectively destroyed with no effect on the destroyer.

True, my fault.

Actually, before asking a question here,  "Independence day" is one of movies that I double-check carefully ('coz google "president" and "alien" keyword brings it up the first...). But it's quite different scene there, and I'm sure the building from the movie in my question is a building, not mothership of some kinds... But thanks for your answer. Although I think the answer is wrong and shouldn't classify this one as answered.
